# How to Check if WP_Query has next page by Wordpress way?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

The snippet:

```
$query = new \WP_Query(
            [
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'paged'          => $paged,
            ]
        );
$query->found_posts; // all of the posts
```

Only the way I have researched is hardcoding every time the piece of code.

```
$posts_per_page = (int) $this->query_vars['posts_per_page'];
$has_next = $paged < ceil( (float) $query->found_posts / $posts_per_page );
```

The problem is duplicating code in all over places I want to calculate the has_next.

This problem could be solved by extending `WP_Query` class and adding the method `has_next_page`.
But this solution overcomplicating than the problem is.

Is there Wordpress way for determine if `WP_Query` has next page without Reinventing the Wheel?

Comment: you could also check the current page against the maxof `wp_query` or as you said extend it you know there's no method for it.

Comment: Extending the class would only work in places where you instantiate your own query object anyway, meaning if you ever needed this for the main query, it would not do the trick to begin with. I’d probably just write a simple stand-alone function here, that gets an optional WP_Query instance passed in, falls back to the global instance if none gets passed – and returns the result of your above “formula”.

Comment: @CBroe, the query is not main query

Comment: That’s why I said, _“that gets an optional WP_Query instance passed in, [and] falls back to the global instance if none gets passed”_ … You would just call the function `query_has_next()` if you wanted this for the main query, and `query_has_next($query)` for a case like you have here.

Answer (score 1):

```
Did you check the following method?

In the template file

$search_args = array(

'post_type'      => 'post',
'post_status'    => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => 3,
'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
);
$search_query = new WP_Query($search_args);


$big = 999999999;

$pages = paginate_links( array(
  'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
  'format' => '?paged=%#%',
  'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
  'total' => $search_query->max_num_pages,


) );

if($pages){
    // exists
}
```